# How to skew an image by moving its vertex?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm trying to find a way to transform an image by translating one of its vertexes.

I have already found various methods for transforming an image like rotation and scaling, but none of the methods involved skewing like so:

[image: example for desired transformation]

There is shearing, but it's not the same since it can move two or more of the image's vertex while I only want to move one.

What can I use that can perform such an operation?

Comment: The linked image looks like it could be produced via 2D [texture mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping).

Comment: The transformation is non-affine so it cant be represented as a matrix. As martineau said in general a texture map is the way to go. What packages are you trying to use for the manipulation?

Comment: The above comments are incorrect. A 4 point perspective transformation should work. It preserves straight lines. See my answer below and also that of Mark Setchell.

Answer (score 2):

I took your *"cat-thing"* and resized it to a nice size, added some perfectly vertical and horizontal white gridlines and added some extra canvas in red at the bottom to give myself room to transform it. That gave me this which is 400 pixels wide and 450 pixels tall:

[image]

I then used **ImageMagick** to do a *"Bilinear Forward Transform"* in Terminal. Basically you give it 4 pairs of points, the first pair is where the top-left corner is before the transform and then where it must move to. The next pair is where the top-right corner is originally followed by where it ends up. Then the bottom-right. Then the bottom-left. As you can see, 3 of the 4 pairs are unmoved - only the bottom-right corner moves. I also made the virtual pixel black so you can see where pixels were invented by the transform in black:

```
convert cat.png -matte -virtual-pixel black -interpolate Spline -distort BilinearForward '0,0 0,0 399,0 399,0 399,349 330,430 0,349 0,349' bilinear.png
```

[image]

I also did a *"Perspective Transform"* using the same transform coordinates:

```
convert cat.png -matte -virtual-pixel black -distort Perspective '0,0 0,0 399,0 399,0 399,349 330,430 0,349 0,349' perspective.png
```

[image]

Finally, to illustrate the difference, I made a flickering comparison between the 2 images so you can see the difference:

[image]

I am indebted to Anthony Thyssen for his excellent work [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#bilinear) which I commend to you.

I understand you were looking for a Python solution and would point out that there is a Python binding to ImageMagick called **Wand** which you may like to use - [here](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.6/).

Note that I only used red and black to illustrate what is going on (atop the Stack Overflow white background) and where aspects of the result come from, you would obviously use white for both!

Answer (score 2):

The perspective transformation is likely what you want, since it preserves straight lines at any angle. (The inverse bilinear only preserves horizontal and vertical straight lines).

Here is how to do it in ImageMagick, Python Wand (based upon ImageMagick) and Python OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

**ImageMagick** 
(Note the +distort makes the output the needed size to hold the full result and is not restricted to the size of the input. Also the -virtual-pixel white sets color of the area outside the image pixels to white. The points are ordered clockwise from the top left in pairs as inx,iny outx,outy)

```
convert cat.png -virtual-pixel white +distort perspective \
"0,0 0,0  359,0 359,0  379,333 306,376  0,333 0,333" \
cat_perspective_im.png
```

[image]

**Python Wand**
(Note the best_fit=true makes the output the needed size to hold the full result and is not restricted to the size of the input.)

```
#!/bin/python3.7
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='cat.png') as img:
    img.virtual_pixel = 'white'
    img.distort('perspective', (0,0, 0,0,  359,0, 359,0,  379,333, 306,376,  0,333, 0,333), best_fit=True)
    img.save(filename='cat_perspective_wand.png')
    display(img)
```

[image]

**Python OpenCV**

```
#!/bin/python3.7

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read source image.
img_src = cv2.imread('cat.png')

# Four corners of source image
# Coordinates are in x,y system with x horizontal to the right and y vertical downward
pts_src = np.float32([[0,0], [359,0], [379,333], [0,333]])

# Four corners of destination image.
pts_dst = np.float32([[0, 0], [359,0], [306,376], [0,333]])

# Get perspecive matrix if only 4 points
m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src,pts_dst)

# Warp source image to destination based on matrix
# size argument is width x height
# compute from max output coordinates
img_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img_src, m, (359+1,376+1), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(255, 255, 255))

# Save output
cv2.imwrite('cat_perspective_opencv.png', img_out)

# Display result
cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", img_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]